# Polyfill in create-react-app does not work

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, cross-browser, create-react-app, polyfills

i have imported react-app-polyfill, however in one of my componenetDidMounts i am trying to parse the window.location.href I am getting errors.

Here is my index.js

```
// This must be the first line in src/index.js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and here is the code that is breaking my application on IE 11

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const curUrl = window.location.href;
    console.log(JSON.parse(curUrl));
}
```

Not sure why this is throwing an error of `Object doesn't support property or method 'repeat'` Any help is appreciated, thank you!

also here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "bulkyBOIZ",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "0s": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "amazon-cognito-auth-js": "^1.3.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.546.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "glamor": "^2.20.40",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^6.0.4",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-scroll-sync": "^0.7.0",
    "react-select": "^2.4.1",
    "react-toastify": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "winston-cloudwatch": "^2.0.9",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development npm run build",
    "build:test": "env-cmd -f .env.test npm run build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server-dev": "nodemon server/index.js | pino-colada",
    "server": "node server/index.js",
    "dev": "run-p server start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.16.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.9.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "express-pino-logger": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "pino-colada": "^1.4.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const curUrl = window.location.href;
> console.log(JSON.parse(curUrl));
> ```

The issue is related to the JSON.parse method, it is used to parse a **JSON** string, if we use it to parse the url (such as "http://localhost:3000/"), it will show the "Object doesn't support property or method 'repeat'" in IE browser and "JSON.parse Error: Invalid character " error in Edge browser.

So, I suggest you modify your code as below:

```
 const curUrl = window.location.href;
 console.log(curUrl);
```

> Object doesn't support property or method 'repeat'

Besides, since the [String.prototype.repeat() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill) doesn't support IE browser, if you want to use it in IE browser, please add the following polyfill:

```
if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
  String.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    'use strict';
    if (this == null)
      throw new TypeError('can\'t convert ' + this + ' to object');

    var str = '' + this;
    // To convert string to integer.
    count = +count;
    // Check NaN
    if (count != count)
      count = 0;

    if (count < 0)
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be non-negative');

    if (count == Infinity)
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be less than infinity');

    count = Math.floor(count);
    if (str.length == 0 || count == 0)
      return '';

    // Ensuring count is a 31-bit integer allows us to heavily optimize the
    // main part. But anyway, most current (August 2014) browsers can't handle
    // strings 1 << 28 chars or longer, so:
    if (str.length * count >= 1 << 28)
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must not overflow maximum string size');

    var maxCount = str.length * count;
    count = Math.floor(Math.log(count) / Math.log(2));
    while (count) {
       str += str;
       count--;
    }
    str += str.substring(0, maxCount - str.length);
    return str;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however this is a deeper issue. This is happening within one of the packages I am using for authentication, and i have no control over it. I will try to add the polyfill to see if that helps, but I was under the impression JSON.parse() is not supported for anything below IE 8

Comment: The polyfill did not help, as when i console.log String.prorotype.repeat it exists as a function, as well as JSON.parse

Comment: It seems that if we create an html page to use the String.prorotype.repeat method, it works well with the polyfill, but if we add the polyfill to reactjs application, it still have some error. So, I suggest you directly log the url, instead of using JSON.parse method to parse it.